# Trying to deploy flask app to heroku, getting h14 error after scaling dyno

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I am trying to deploy my flask application to Heroku but I check the logs and keep getting this H14 error saying that no web processes are running. I did `heroku ps:scale worker=1` command after `heroku push master` and it says the it was able to scale a dyno  `Scaling dynos... done, now running worker at 1:Free`. although I still get the H14 error. Any reason why I am getting this error message or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to scale up the web dyno (Flask indicates you will have incoming traffic)

```
heroku ps:scale web=1 --app appname
```

Comment: So my app name in heroku is "covid-flask" so the command would be "heroku ps:scale web=1 --app covid-flask"? I get "appname", but what would be "app"?

Comment: --app is the param name required by Heroku CLI (to indicate you are setting the name of the app), no need to change that

Comment: Okay, so i did that command and got an error saying " Couldn't find that process type (web)."

Comment: How do you deploy your application? Docker? Github? Procfile? At some point you define the process type, which should be web

Comment: Procfile. the python file that holds that runs the process is called app.py, so the Procfile looks like "worker: python app.py"

Comment: Try `web: python app.py`

Comment: That seemed to help. I was able to go to the url without having an error right away, but the app timed out and gave my an error code H20 (app timeout) and then an error code H10 (app crashed).

Comment: Do you set the port using $PORT?

Comment: No, ```app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)``` like this

Comment: `app.run(port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)), host='0.0.0.0')`